# Adding modules to Python3

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-12.04, python-module

I am trying to use the library matplotlib, but can't get it to work with python3. The python 2.7.3 interpreter I have finds it without a problem though. What steps do I need to take for python3 to have access to this library?

Comment: My apologies, I'm new at this

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html) is usful for you :). Please make sure the your `python` command is the python3 binary. It usualy is `python3` in ubuntu.

Comment: @atupal, I've been using the python3 command. python runs python 2.7.3. Is this something I should change?

Comment: @DavisYoshida: No, that is fine.

Comment: @DavisYoshida For example, you can `git clone git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git` and then `cd matplotlib` , `python3 setup.py install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle your Python packages, I suggest you rather use pip than your OS package manager.

To install pip, just follow [the instructions](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html).

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
python ez_setup.py
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

should be enough.

Be sure to use python3 command if the python on your path is version 2.x

After having install pip, you will be able to download and install the packages from [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) by running

```
pip install PACKAGE_NAME
```

so for instance, for matplotlib

```
pip install matplotlib
```

If pip is already installed for Python2, the command may be `pip3` or `pip-3.x` to install packages for Python3.

If you have errors while installing matplotlib, make sure that you have the necessary packages to compile it. On Ubuntu I suppose

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

should be enough for a basic installation though.

Comment: I followed these instructions, but ended up getting the error "Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/matplotlib"

Comment: Could you post the full error, or the content of the log file, otherwise it is impossible to know what went wrong.

Comment: Make sure you have the `python3-dev` package installed, and make sure that CFLAGS and LDFLAGS are unset when running the command.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't have that installed. My face is red.

Comment: Same as above, post the log.

Comment: This I managed to fix it, I was missing another package. Sorry for the bother, I feel like I'm trying to put together legos in a room with no light a lot of the time with this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Python 3 matplotlib for Ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

**EDIT**: This package exists from Ubuntu 13.04. If you have an older Ubuntu, then you'll have to either

- install it manually: https://gist.github.com/mlongval/4950532
- or install it from a third-party repository: http://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~cuvelier/mainsu22.html

Comment: apt didn't find that package. My problem is that I don't know enough about how the modules are stored and referenced I guess.

Comment: The problem is not just how it is stored; matplotlib includes compiled, non-Python code, so just placing a package where it needs to be is not sufficient. I edited in some more info for older Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure it is in the path for your python3 and that your version of matplotlib is compatible with python3.  What I would do is open you python2.7 and python3 interpreters and enter the following:

```
>>>import sys
>>>print sys.path
```

and see how the outputs compare.  You also could download and compile the matplotlib with python3 instead of python2.7.  You would just need to run the setup.py file with python3 instead of python2.7.