# I am getting ImportError no module named pytube from python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I have installed pytube by following command

```
sudo pip install pytube
```

It's ok when I import pytube from python 2.x. 
 But I am getting ImportError while importing from python3

Comment: I would guess `pip` is for python 2 on your setup - try `which`? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding modules to Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534556/adding-modules-to-python3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the package with pip3 (`sudo pip3 install pytube`), in some operating systems pip refers to python2 and pip3 refers to python3.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install pytube3:

```
sudo pip3 install pytube3
```

And after that you should be able to import pytube